# Can we use dynamic link without a firebase hosted webpage?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-hosting, firebase-dynamic-links

This might be a weird question, but first let me tell my problem. I have a contact form which is written in php . And after i completed the work, i get to this point that firebase does not support php code. So i need a Solution for that.
There are this case that i just hoste my website with another server.
Problem here i use dynamic links. So is it possible to use dynamic links with a webpage which is not hosted on firebase?

Solution 2.
I rewrite the code . But the in which language?
I domt wanna use cloud functions. I wanna use for example javascript. Is this possible?

If you have also any other solution please write them below.
Thanks for answering the questions.

this is my code

```
<section id="page-details">
                <div class="container">
                    <div id="contact-details" class="full-width">
                        <div class="one-third">
                            <div id="contact-us-form" class="grey-corner-box">
                                <form action="contact-from-handler.php" method="post" class="contact-form init" novalidate="novalidate" data-status="init">
                                    <fieldset>
                                        <legend>
                                            <div>
                                                <span class="bold">Drop</span> us a line
                                            </div>

                                            <?php
                                            $contact_name = $contact_email = $contact_website = $contact_message = '';

                                            if(isset($_REQUEST['error']))
                                            {
                                                $contact_name    = $_REQUEST['contact_name'];
                                                $contact_email   = $_REQUEST['contact_email'];
                                                $contact_website = $_REQUEST['contact_website'];
                                                $contact_message = $_REQUEST['contact_message'];
                                            }
                                            ?>

                                            <?php if(isset($_REQUEST['error'])) { ?>
                                                <div style="background:red;color:white;padding:5px;margin:5px 0;clear:both;font-size:14px;">Some required field was missing!</div>
                                            <?php } elseif(isset($_REQUEST['success'])) { ?>
                                                <div style="background:green;color:white;padding:5px;margin:5px 0;clear:both;font-size:14px;">Successfully send your request!</div>
                                            <?php } ?>
                                        </legend>

                                        <ul>
                                            <li class="select-three">
                                                <div>
                                                    <label for="input-name">Name:*</label>
                                                    <input type="text" name="contact_name" value="<?php echo $contact_name; ?>" size="40" class="form-control default-input" aria-invalid="false">
                                                </div>
                                                <div>
                                                    <label for="input-email">E-mail:*</label>
                                                    <input type="email" name="contact_email" value="<?php echo $contact_email; ?>" size="40" class="form-control input-email default-input" aria-invalid="false">
                                                </div>
                                                <div>
                                                    <label for="input-website">Website:*</label>
                                                    <input type="text" name="contact_website" value="<?php echo $contact_website; ?>" size="40" class="form-control default-input" aria-invalid="false">
                                                </div>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <div>
                                                    <label for="contact_message">Message:*</label>
                                                    <textarea name="contact_message" cols="40" rows="5" class="form-control textarea form-control" aria-invalid="false"><?php echo $contact_message; ?></textarea>
                                                </div>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <div class="submit-contact default-submit">
                                                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit-btn theme-btn">
                                                </div>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </fieldset>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

and then the contact-us-form

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST))
{
    $data = $_POST;
    $data['email_receiver'] = "emsilll";
    

    $error = FALSE;
    if(!$_POST['contact_name'])
    {
        $error = TRUE;
        $field = 'contact_name';
    }
    elseif(!$_POST['contact_email'])
    {
        $error = TRUE;
        $field = 'contact_email';
    }
    elseif(!$_POST['contact_website'])
    {
        $error = TRUE;
        $field = 'contact_website';
    }
    elseif(!$_POST['contact_message'])
    {
        $error = TRUE;
        $field = 'contact_message';
    }

    if($error)
    {
        header('location:contact-us.php?error=yes&' . http_build_query($data));
        die();
    }

    $to      = $data['email_receiver'];
    $from    = "info@" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
    $subject = "Subject: " . $data['contact_name'] . "";
    $message = "E-Mail: " . $data["contact_email"] . "\n" . $message = "Website: " . $data["contact_website"] . "\n" . "Message: " . $data["contact_message"];
    $headers = "From: " . $from . "" . "\r\n" . "Reply-To: " . $from . "" . "\r\n" . 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    
    header('location:contact-us.php?success=yes');
}
?>
```

Comment: What are dynamic links?

Comment: @Phil If a user opens a Dynamic Link on iOS or Android, they can be taken directly to the linked content in your native app. If a user opens the same Dynamic Link in a desktop browser, they can be taken to the equivalent content on your website.

In addition, Dynamic Links work across app installs: if a user opens a Dynamic Link on iOS or Android and doesn't have your app installed, the user can be prompted to install it; then, after installation, your app starts and can access the link. So sou can create dynamic links only in firebase console. Its a product from firebase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firebase Dynamic Links don't have to be on the same domain as your website.  It's common practice to host them on a different domain, or on a subdomain.  The actual web forwarding address of the Dynamic link is specifying by the `link` parameter [[1]](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/dynamic-links/link-shortener#request_body), and doesn't have to be the same as the domain of the Dynamic link.

Firebase provides a free `<subdomain>.page.link` domain for your usage [[2]](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links#custom-link-domains).  You can also setup dynamic links with a custom domain at `<subdomain>.yourdomain.com` or `<subdomain>.yourdomain.com/path`[[3]](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/custom-domains), which uses Firebase Hosting.

If you would like to switch your entire website over to Firebase Hosting to take advantage of our other features (like the CDN), you can setup your PHP site to run on Cloud Run [[4]](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy/php), and setup a rewrite to it using Hosting [[5]](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/cloud-run).